# putting shell_exec() output into array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a line of php :

```
$output = shell_exec('ps aux | grep 9902 | awk \'{print $11" "$2}\'');
```

`print $output;` will give the output :

```
rtmpgw 10089
/usr/bin/vlc 10107
sh 10123
grep 10125
```

I tried using this next line to put the above output into an array.

```
$oparray = explode(" ", trim($output));
```

It works, but not as expected. `print_r($oparray);` will give the following output :

```
Array
(
    [0] => rtmpgw
    [1] => 10089
/usr/bin/vlc
    [2] => 10107
sh
    [3] => 10123
grep
    [4] => 10125
)
```

This confuses me as I would expect an Index number for each value but three of the values appear to be without indices.

So I suppose my question here is two parts

1. What is going on in the output above
2. Can anyone help me get a useful array that looks like this :

   Array
   (
       [0] => rtmpgw
       [1] => 10089
       [2] => /usr/bin/vlc
       [3] => 10107
       [4] => sh
       [5] => 10123
       [6] => grep
       [7] => 10125
   )

Thanks~

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The lines in `shell_exec` output are separated by the `end-of-line` symbol - and that's different from normal whitespace, that's why `explode` doesn't account for it.

You can use [**preg_split**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) instead, with `\s` character class matching *both* normal whitespace and EOL.

```
$oparray = preg_split('/\s+/', trim($output));
```

Comment: Perfect Array. Simple solution and works good. Thanks so much.

Comment: this solution will not work well for output name those contains whitespace! For example a file name like **Hello world** , this solution will create `[0]=>['Hello','world']`

Answer (score 10):

Try this:

```
<?php
$text = 'rtmpgw 10089
/usr/bin/vlc 10107
sh 10123
grep 10125';

$oparray = preg_split("#[\r\n]+#", $text);

print_r($oparray);
?>
```

> ```
> Array
> (
>     [0] => rtmpgw 10089
>     [1] => /usr/bin/vlc 10107
>     [2] => sh 10123
>     [3] => grep 10125
> )
> ```

Comment: This worked perfectly, except I had to add trim() to the $text variable, like $response_array = preg_split("#[\r\n]+#", trim($output)); Otherwise, it returned an extra index.

Answer (score 1):

```
$array = array();
foreach(preg_split("/((\r?\n)|(\r\n?))/", $subject) as $line){
    $oparray = explode(" ", trim($line));
    $array[] = $oparray[0];
    $array[] = $oparray[1];
}
```

Comment: Just a pointer, you don't need to declare `$array` if you are using `[]=`

Comment: it's true that you don't need Array(), but I often include it to make sure that the variable is empty.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to use `preg_split` as this can be achieved with `explode` and should perform better. Output is separated using end of line characters. Simply use `explode` with `PHP_EOL`. Considering, you also wish to have items separated by spaces, you'll also need to do a `str_replace`.

```
$array = explode(PHP_EOL, str_replace(' ', PHP_EOL, $output));
```

If you are left with an empty string at the end of your array, use:

```
$array = explode(PHP_EOL, rtrim(str_replace(' ', PHP_EOL, $output)));
```